# React-Native: Can I store JWT in AsyncStorage because the tokens expire anyway?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jwt

In my server I can set the JWT tokens to expire after a given period of time.

Can I simply have this in my app?

```
async function getUserDetails() {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token') //got this token from successful login
    const data = await axios.get(apiurl+'&JWT='+token)
    console.log(data)
}
```

By the time the attacker physically gets a hold of the phone, jailbreak it and connect it to her computer, the JWT must have expired? Or am I not understanding something here?

Answer (score 1):

AsyncStorage can not expire data. you have to use a trick. when you are setting your token. just set another key as **date** equal to `new Date()`. then in the root of your project setup a function which get **date** from AsyncStorage and checks the time passed from now to the time you saved token. if its bigger than your desired time just remve token from AsyncStorage

Answer (score 0):

By the way AsyncStorage is not secure. for saving your sensetive information you can use [react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain)